# How to prove fundamental lemma of homogeneous linear equations using induction.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am unable to see how to apply induction on 2 natural numbers m,n. And what would be base step and hypothesis step in the proof. Any help is deeply appreciated .where m is no of equations and n is no. of unknowns.

Comment: And what is the fundamental lemma of homogeneous linear equations?

Comment: System of m homogeneous equations in n unknowns has non trivial solutions, if m<n.

Comment: Perhaps the induction could be on $n-m$, the base case being $n-m=1$.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: I did attempt your suggested notion, but that creates system of m eqn in m+1 unknowns , still unable to solve some preliminary steps there .

Comment: For $m$ equations in $m+1$ unknowns, think about what happens when you bring to reduced row-echelon form.

Comment: Did that help any?

Comment: Proved the lemma using reduced row echelon theory. shall update the proof soon.